# Is there any setting in ubuntu so that the admin can provide a math when someone starts the computer?

Tags: ubuntu, password-management

Some website test the user either he is robot or not, providing a math problem(i.e.2+3=?).I want to set a math problem(i.e.traverse a given binary tree) when someone open computer system shows the math problem and requires its solution.

Comment: Interesting.  Are you wanting it to provide the math problem to every attempted login, like to the system's SSH server, or TTYs, or the normal GUI logon session only?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a `pam` module.  You may need to write your own.

There is a pam module that does text captchas.